# See if component are damage or are bad connected

Tags: gpio, hardware

I am very very new to Raspberry, I have a raspberry pi 3 model V1.2, and I want to move my raspberry with 2 motor driven wheels and a 1 HG7881CP H-bridge, I used a java code for my robot, I have put this jar into my raspberry, in this java code I have specified this pin:

```
motorleft  = Motor  [ gpiomotor pincw 8 pinccw 9  ]  position: LEFT
motorright = Motor  [ gpiomotor pincw 12 pinccw 13  ]  position: RIGHT
motors = Actuators [ motorleft , motorright  ] private position: BOTTOM
```

Other code configuration of this raspberry :

```
motor.left=gpio.motor
motor.left.pin.cw=8
motor.left.pin.ccw=9
motor.left.private=false
motor.right=gpio.motor
motor.right.pin.cw=12
motor.right.pin.ccw=13
motor.right.private=false
```

But when I start my jar, the wheels doesn't move and there is no error, I know that with this poor information is difficult to help me, but, there is any way to see what am I doing wrong?OR if this 3 component are broken ? Or something? 
I have execute the script ./pintest and here is the output:
[image: pintestOutput]

[image]

Comment: Assuming you have the common 4-6V DC wheels like these https://www.ebay.com/i/281686235135?chn=ps&dispItem=1 you could connect them to a few  batteries or a 5V source (like a phone charger). They should spin in one direction and when you reverse the connections (VCC and ground) it should spin in the opposite direction.

Comment: @SteveRobillard is what I have! How I can connect them to a few battery or 5v ? I have never did it before

Comment: They have two metal lugs (these are on the end where the motor is -
 the end furthest from the center of the wheel - and are usually silver or brass colored) connect positive to one and ground to the other.

Comment: sorry for the request, do you have some explication image to doing this? I have never use eletronic components before, I have search some image on google but I didn't found anything usefull. thanks

Comment: Given that you have never done anything like this before, why did you choose this as a first project? I am not saying you can't do it, but you have a long steep road head. How are you powering the Pi? Do you have a 3 or 4 battery (AA, AAA, C, or D) case?

Comment: I use a power bank or phone charger... I have to do this for a university exam, I want to learn how to do this, but anybody explain me before how to do that =(

Comment: power up your Pi and then use the 5v and ground pins (see diagram here https://pinout.xyz) then using a couple of wires, connect the other ends of the wires to the two terminals on the motor.

Comment: Thank you @SteveRobillard, I will try it and let you know!

Comment: just be careful not to touch any other pin or connect the two wires together, this can destroy your Pi. Is this a course you are currently in? if so is it the beginning or end of the term?

Comment: If i have understand; I have to put 1 female Jumper on the 34 pin(Ground), and the male of the jumper on one of the lug of my tire wheel gear motor, and do the same for the second lug (changing the pin to put the jumper), it is right?

Comment: almost use a female to male jumper (if you have one) and connect it to pin 34 (ground) and one lug on the motor. take a second female to male jumper and connect it to pin 2 (5v) and the other lug of the motor. If you don't have any female to male jumpers you can cut the other end off and strip a few millimeters off the end. if you do need to cut and strip the wire make sure to disconnect it first.

Comment: @SteveRobillard you can see that in the picture, I have try what you eplain to me ( the raspberry is connected to a phone charger), but nothing appens, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's not 5V and ground.  That's GPIO 21 and ground.

Comment: Again use the link I I gave you above to make sure you are using the correct pins on the Pi. If you can't get this part correct you will have little luck getting things to work correctly.

Comment: Move the orange wire to the first pin in the same column (there are 2 columns and 13 rows), which is the 5V pin as @goldilocks pointed out. Also, it is hard to tell but make sure the wheel is off the table so it does not drive off pulling you Pi to the floor damaging it.

Comment: @SteveRobillard No there are 2 rows and 20 columns ;)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61393/discussion-on-question-by-liz-lamperouge-see-if-component-are-damage-or-are-bad).

Comment: thank you to all, last days I was so blind and stupid with the configuration that I haven't see that I was doing the configuration on the opposite side XD 
I have tried what Steve Robillard tolds to me and It work ;) If you ask this question with your suggestion I will choose it!  The last thing, to try if the sonar sensor hcsr04 works and are not damage, what I have to do?